# Facebook Auto wall Posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have implemented Facebook Like stream, in which users can post status, photos and URL's on their stream.
Now I have given an option to post on Facebook as well. I have given a checkbox and on clicking the Post Button it will check the checkbox value,if its checked then it will post on facebook as well.
This has done successfully,but its showing Facebook Feed Dialog, I want to post automatically without showing the Feed Dialog
Below code I am using on post button

```
 if ($("#fbpostcheck").attr("checked")) {
  FB.ui({
                        method: 'feed',
                        link: 'http://mywebsite.com',
                        picture: 'my image',
                        name: 'Stream',
                        caption: "FB post",
                        description: "User Entered Description"
                    }, function (response) { });
 }
```

Is it possible to auto post on FaceBook without showing feed dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've use the `Dialog` that's why it is showing the Dialog. Use `FB.api` instead.

(**Note:** You can only post on the current **user's** wall, not to his/her friends- that has been disabled by the facebook now.)

To post on the user's wall, you can simply use-

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { link: 'http://mywebsite.com', picture: 'my image', ETC..}, function(response) {
   if (!response || response.error) {
      alert('Error occured');
   } else {
      alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
   }
});
```

Comment: I want to post on the current user wall, but without showing dialog

Comment: Thanks It working as per I was expecting. But if user is not login, then its giving me error, Can I save current userID some where and pass it to feed?

Comment: If user is not logged in , you can post only using the `app_access_token`; else this will throw error. So, if you want to post without login use `app_access_token` and then post; you can save userId in your database or anywhere(i dont know what your app do). OR, befre using this function use- `FB.getLoginstatus` to whether or not user is logged-in and then do the posting. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/